# The IO operation has been aborted when I try to open serial port

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have software that opens a serial port using C# and it does good with hardware com but with usb 2 serial com ports I get this error

> the i/o operation has been aborted
>   because of either a thread exist or an
>   application request

I don't know what it means... although hyperterminal works very well at the same machine.

My code looks like this :

```
SerialPort.Open();
```

after initialization of course by the way my code work very will with Hardware Com Port !

Comment: Which version of the .net framework are you running?

Comment: i tried both 2.0 and 3.5 the same error

Comment: Try reading this [Blog post](http://blog.zachsaw.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html) from an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194948/what-is-the-cause-of-system-io-ioexception-on-windows-xp-embedded-version)

Comment: Don't disconnect the USB cable when you have to port opened.  USB drivers suck that way.  .NET 4 has a counter-measure against their behavior.

Comment: Try 4.0, you might want to reboot after you install it (or maybe the install requires it)...

Comment: @Mike: That's good information.  Even with the fix, though, the .NET serial port API has horrible design flaws.  Using the thread pool for serial I/O is just crazy -- serial ports never have high enough throughput to justify a worker thread, nevermind a worker thread per operation.  Side effects of using the thread pool?  Extra context switches, need to synchronize threads, inability to access UI from event handlers.  And the "parameter checking" is overzealous and rejects valid serial port names (at least).

Comment: I wrote a serial port wrapper using C++/CLI that handles an unlimited number of ports with a single worker thread and triggers the user-visible events on the main thread.  In comparison to the Microsoft "race condition by default" this design takes care of all cross-thread synchronization (without explicit locking, I might add, message passing ftw) and integrates with the Device Manager APIs so you can find and open a USB serial port based on VID/PID, etc.  Hopefully someday I'll be allowed to publish this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all it really helpful comments 
the problem was combination between WIndows xp and .Net framework 2
when i have upgraded to windows 7 with (default .Net frame work shipped with win7) 
which i think 3.5 every thing goes ok and my application work very will 
all other issues related to [microsoft](http://blog.zachsaw.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html) i but it between try catch block